# How to deploy a javafx application as an executable jar or exe with gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, exe, executable-jar

I want to make an application in javafx. Im new to java fx and gradle so currently I just messing around with things. One of the first things I wanted to try was to build an application to an executable jar or exe. I have tried several things but I never get a simple jar to execute. it does not execute when I double click it. and when I try to execute it from the command line I get this error: **Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application**
I tried many solutions I found on the web but without success.

This is the code of the application:

```
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label("hello world");
        Scene scene = new Scene(label);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

and this is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
}

group 'org.example'
version ''

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
}

javafx {
    version = "15.0.1"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls','javafx.fxml' ]
}
mainClassName = 'org.example.Main'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.example.Main'
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

does someone know how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `jlink` to build a Java runtime that includes the JavaFX modules.

Use `jpackage` (from JDK 14 and later) to bundle your application using that runtime.  That will give you an .exe launcher and platform-specific installers.

Gradle 'Exec' tasks can easily run both of those tools for you as part of your build.

To make things easier, you might consider using a JDK that includes the JavaFX modules so you don't have to mess around with configuring the JavaFX SDK and the module path.
There are OpenJDK builds from Azul and Bellsoft that include JavaFX.

Here is an example of the sort of task I use with jpackage.  My 'appImage' task copies files to prepare for bundling, my jlink task creates the runtime image.  This task creates an application image that is runnable which I use for a second invocation of jpackage to produce the installers.  You could also just zip up this image if you don't need an installer, but each image is platform-specific as it contains native launchers and the JRE to use:

```
task jpackageImage(type: Exec, dependsOn: [jlink, appImage]) {
    workingDir = project.projectDir
    inputs.property('consoleApp', project.consoleApp)
    inputs.property('vendorName', project.vendorName)
    if (project.hasProperty('copyright')) {
        inputs.property('copyright', project.copyright)
    }
    // TODO set input directory
    inputs.dir "${buildDir}${File.separator}image${File.separator}app"
    inputs.dir "${buildDir}${File.separator}image${File.separator}runtime"
    // define outputs
    outputs.dir "${buildDir}${File.separator}application"
    
    // in a doFirst in case values change (e.g. archive name gets version bump)
    // after configuration phase
    doFirst {
        // Error: Application output directory XXXXXXXXXXXXXX already exists.
        def tmpRoot = "$buildDir/tmp/image"
        project.delete tmpRoot
        project.delete "${buildDir}${File.separator}application"
        
        // resource directories need to exist
        project.mkdir resourceDir

        //file("${buildDir}/image/app/README.txt").text = "This file should be installed."

        def appName = project.applicationName // project.applicationName.replaceAll(" ","")
        def copyrightStr = project.hasProperty('copyright') ? project.copyright.toString() : "Copyright (c) ${year} ${vendorName}".toString().trim()
        def tmp = [
            "${jpackageTool}",
            '--type', 'app-image', // Valid values on Windows are: {"app-image", "exe", "msi"}
            '--verbose',
            '--temp', tmpRoot,
            '--app-version', project.version,
            '--input', "${buildDir}${File.separator}image${File.separator}app",
            '--runtime-image', "${buildDir}${File.separator}image${File.separator}runtime",
            '--name', appName,
            '--main-jar', "libs${File.separator}${configurations.runtime.artifacts.files.singleFile.name}",
            '--main-class', mainClass,
            '--resource-dir', resourceDir,
            '--icon', iconFileStr,
            '--description', project.description,
            '--vendor', vendorName,
            //'--category', 'Utility',
            '--copyright', copyrightStr,
            '--dest', "${buildDir}${File.separator}application",
            ]
        // Use a console app for easier debugging (log messages/debug prints are visible)
        if (osName.startsWith('windows')) {
            // Windows-specific options
            //'--win-menu',
            //'--win-menu-group', vendorName,
            //'--win-upgrade-uuid', project.upgradeUUID,
            //'--win-shortcut',
            // for a console application
            if (project.consoleApp) {
                tmp.addAll(['--win-console'])
            }
        }
        if (osName.startsWith('mac')) {
            tmp.addAll([
                // macOS-specific options
                //This name must be less than 16 characters long and be suitable for displaying in the menu bar and the application Info window.
                '--mac-package-name', project.macPkgName,
                '--mac-package-identifier', project.macPkgIndentifier,
                //'--mac-package-signing-prefix', <prefix string>,
                //'--mac-sign', // Request that the bundle be signed
                //'--mac-signing-keychain', <file path>,
                //'--mac-signing-key-user-name', '<team name>'
            ])
        }
        commandLine = tmp
        println commandLine
    }

    // workaround https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8254920
    doLast {
        if (osName.startsWith('windows') && jlinkCompression == 2) {
            project.copy {
                from "${buildDir}\\application\\${project.applicationName}\\runtime\\bin\\zip.dll"
                into "${buildDir}\\application\\${project.applicationName}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I really should just make a proper Gradle plugin for this stuff at some point.

You can learn more about jpackage at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html

Comment: do you have a source where i can learn how jpackage works ?

Comment: @yentepaternotte I've expanded the answer with one of my Gradle tasks for running jpackage and provided a link to the documentation.

Comment: @yentepaternotte You don't necessarily have to configure everything yourself manually. Check out the [badass-jlink-plugin](https://badass-jlink-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/) for Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a short-time, somewhat unstable fix for examples like yours, you could have another class in the same classpath as the current one, with a main method. What you would do in the body of that method is to do Main.main(args). This will trick the program into not thinking it is a Java application, making it work properly. Also, you have to change the main class names to the name of the new class.

Source: https://edencoding.com/runtime-components-error/

Comment: isnt there a solution that is stable and for the long term?

Comment: @yentepaternotte there is, but it is rather hard. nevertheless, if you do want it, it is in the source I provided.